# One View for Edit and Add in controller function itself using CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller, controller

I am using in the Below code for edit data as shown below but not working for me.

```
$tbody .= '<input placeholder="Start Date" id="ed" type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="start_date" value="'if($config->metrcsettingconf_master_id == $store_products->master_id){ echo $config->metrcsettingconf_startdate} else{ echo ""}'">';
```

In the code value="" in the input field of form. Add is working fine but after adding data, i want to edit form same company and store selection.

```
function get_master() {
        $store_id  = $this->input->post('store_id');
        $get_store = $this->common->get_row(array(
            'store_id' => $store_id
        ), DBPREFIX . "store");
        $store = $get_store->store_state_id;
        $company = $get_store->store_company_id;
        $this->session->set_userdata('store', $store);
        $this->session->set_userdata('company', $company);
        $data['master'] = $master = $this->common->get_whereresult(DBPREFIX . 'apimaster', array('master_status' => 1, 'master_state' => $store), 'master_name');

        $tbody = '';
        foreach ($master as $store_products) {
            $config = $this->common->get_whereresult(DBPREFIX . 'metrcsetting_conf', array('metrcsettingconf_status' => 1, 'metrcsettingconf_master_id' => $store_products->master_id, 'metrcsettingconf_company_id' => $company, 'metrcsettingconf_store_id' => $store_id));

            $tbody .= '<div class="row">';
            $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
            $tbody .= '<div class="panel panel-default">';
            $tbody .= '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">';
            $tbody .= '<h4 class="panel-title" style="height:18px;">';
            $tbody .= '<form action="add_metrcsettingmaster/'  . $store_products->master_id . '" method="post">';
            $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">';
            $tbody .= '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="master_id" href="#collapseOne'. $store_products->master_id .'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne'. $store_products->master_id .'">'  . $store_products->master_name . '</a>';
            $tbody .= '<input id="master_idd" type="hidden" value="'  . $store_products->master_id . '">';
            $tbody .= '</div>';

            $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 start_date" style="margin-top:-8px;">';
            $tbody .= '<input placeholder="Start Date" id="ed" type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="start_date" value="">';
            $tbody .= '<span class="start_datetext">Sync Active</span>';
            $tbody .= '</div>';

            $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 end_date" style="margin-top:-8px;">';
            $tbody .= '<input placeholder="End Date" id="jd" type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="end_date" value="">';
            $tbody .= '<span class="end_datetext">Sync Expire</span>';
            $tbody .= '</div>';

            $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 time" style="margin-top:-5px;">';
            $tbody .= '<input type="time" name="time" class="form-control" value="">';
            $tbody .= '<span class="timetext">Sync Time</span>';
            $tbody .= '</div>';

            $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: -5px">';
            $tbody .= '<select name="days[]" class="form-control status chosen-select" multiple="multiple">';
            $tbody .= '<option value="Monday">Monday</option>';
            $tbody .= '<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>';
            $tbody .= '<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>';
            $tbody .= '<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>';
            $tbody .= '<option value="Friday">Friday</option>';
            $tbody .= '<option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>';
            $tbody .= '<option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>';   
            $tbody .= '</select>';                    
            $tbody .= '</div>';


            $tbody .= '<div class="form-group  col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-8px;text-align:center;">';
            $tbody .= '<label class="switch">';
            $tbody .= '<p style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:-60px;"> Manual </p>';
            $tbody .= '<p style="margin-top:-27px;margin-left:60px;"> Auto </p>';
            $tbody .= '<input type="checkbox" name="manauto" id="chkPassportt" value="">';
            $tbody .= '<span class="slider round"></span>';
            //$tbody .= 'form_error('"manauto"');';
            $tbody .= '</label>';
            $tbody .= '</div>';
            $tbody .= '<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 pull-right" style="margin-top:-8px;">';
            $tbody .= '<input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
            $tbody .= '</div>';
            $tbody .= '</form>';
            $tbody .= '</h4>';
            $tbody .= '</div>';
            $tbody .= '<div id="collapseOne'. $store_products->master_id .'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">';
            $tbody .= '<div class="panel-body">';
            $tbody .= '<div id="childdata">';

            $master_id  = $store_products->master_id;
            $data['child'] = $child = $this->common->get_whereresult(DBPREFIX . 'apichild', array('child_status' => 1, 'child_master' => $master_id), 'child_apiname');

            foreach ($child as $store_products) {

                $tbody .= '<div class="row">';
                $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">';
                $tbody .= '<div class="panel panel-default">';
                $tbody .= '<div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">';
                $tbody .= '<h4 class="panel-title" style="height:18px;">';
                $tbody .= '<form action="add_metrcsettingchild/'  . $store_products->child_id . '" method="post">';
                $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">';
                $tbody .= '<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" id="child_id" href="#collapseOne'. $store_products->child_id .'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne'. $store_products->child_id .'">'  . $store_products->child_apiname . '</a>';
                $tbody .= '<input id="child_idd" type="hidden" value="'  . $store_products->child_id . '">';
                $tbody .= '</div>';

                $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 start_date" style="margin-top:-8px;">';
                $tbody .= '<input placeholder="Start Date" id="ed" type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="start_date" value="">';
                $tbody .= '<span class="start_datetext">Sync Active</span>';
                $tbody .= '</div>';

                $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 end_date" style="margin-top:-8px;">';
                $tbody .= '<input placeholder="End Date" id="jd" type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" name="end_date" value="">';
                $tbody .= '<span class="end_datetext">Sync Expire</span>';
                $tbody .= '</div>';

                $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 time" style="margin-top:-5px;">';
                $tbody .= '<input type="time" name="time">';
                $tbody .= '<span class="timetext">Sync Time</span>';
                $tbody .= '</div>';

                $tbody .= '<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="margin-top: -5px">';
                $tbody .= '<select name="days[]" class="form-control status chosen-select" multiple="multiple">';
                $tbody .= '<option value="Monday">Monday</option>';
                $tbody .= '<option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>';
                $tbody .= '<option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>';
                $tbody .= '<option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>';
                $tbody .= '<option value="Friday">Friday</option>';
                $tbody .= '<option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>';
                $tbody .= '<option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>';   
                $tbody .= '</select>';                    
                $tbody .= '</div>';

                $tbody .= '<div class="form-group  col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="margin-top:-8px;text-align:center;">';
                $tbody .= '<label class="switch">';
                $tbody .= '<p style="margin-top:10px;margin-left:-60px;"> Manual </p>';
                $tbody .= '<p style="margin-top:-27px;margin-left:60px;"> Auto </p>';
                $tbody .= '<input type="checkbox" name="manauto" id="chkPassportt">';
                $tbody .= '<span class="slider round"></span>';
                //$tbody .= 'form_error('"manauto"');';
                $tbody .= '</label>';
                $tbody .= '</div>';
                $tbody .= '<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 pull-right" style="margin-top:-8px;">';
                $tbody .= '<input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">';
                $tbody .= '</div>';
                $tbody .= '</form>';
                $tbody .= '</h4>';
                $tbody .= '</div>';
                $tbody .= '<div id="collapseOne'. $store_products->child_id .'" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">';
                $tbody .= '<div class="panel-body">';
                $tbody .= '<div id="childdata"></div>';                         
                $tbody .= '</div>';
                $tbody .= '</div>'; 
                $tbody .= '</div>'; 
                $tbody .= '</div>';
                $tbody .= '</div>';
            }
            $tbody .= '</div>';                         
            $tbody .= '</div>';
            $tbody .= '</div>'; 
            $tbody .= '</div>'; 
            $tbody .= '</div>';
            $tbody .= '</div>';

        }

        echo $tbody;
    }
```

In the code value="" in the input field of form. Add is working fine but after adding data, i want to edit form.

Comment: what is the exact problem? `i want to edit form` is very unclear! AND using static `<div id="any_ID">` within you loops will not work (give you headaches), if the loop provides more then one result

Comment: The View Using $tbody is rendering properly, when i trying to use php inside that one- like if($store_products->child_apiname == 1){ echo 1;}else{echo 2;} the 500 internal server error is coming.